# How to define break condition for WHILE loop?

Tags: sql, while-loop, sql-server-2016

The query I have might well be simple, but I've tied myself in knots trying to figure it.

I have two tables. The first holds a CustomerID at a point in time, and the other tracks updates (when some data changes, the customer is assigned a new ID to differentiate). So, as an example, CustomerID '0001' could update to '0002', and subsequently to '0004' (picked arbitrarily; just the next available ID).

What I'm trying to do is loop through the update statement so that it tracks the entire footprint of the update - some CustomerIDs might not have changed, others may have gone through several iterations.

I've managed to get this done with an update statement, though putting it in a WHILE loop causes it to loop infinitely as the last batch of updates will recur indefinitely.

What would be the best method for breaking the loop once all the source columns match the target columns?

The structure of the source table is FromCustomerID, ToCustomerID and MergedDateTime.

My existing update statement is:

```
UPDATE
  a
SET
  NewCustomerId = b.ToCustomerId
FROM
  dbo.Job7509_Q4_Loyalty_CustomerID_Updates a
  INNER JOIN Customers.dbo.MergedNames b ON a.NewCustomerId = b.FromCustomerId
```

Comment: The best way would be to not use loops at all. In 2016 version (and higher) you can use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) which is SQL Server built in data history mechanism - that would probably be the best way.

Comment: *"The best way would be to not use loops at all"* This. Exactly this.

Comment: I certainly would want to avoid loops in general, granted. I don’t believe that the tables in question are system-versioned, certainly not the target table. Thank you very much for the suggestion though.

Comment: @HendrixAndChill . . . You should ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want implemented.  A `WHILE` loop is highly unlikely to be the best solution.